# VS2010 Intellisense problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

This question actually is an implicit answer, since I could fix the problem in the meantime for myself. But I wanted to publish my experience, since some other developers might have a similar problems.

The problem:

I am using VS2010 prof SP1 on Windows XP SP3, pure C++ only. (AntiVirus software present). 
Since some days Intellisense - which is quite helpful under normal conditions - does not work anymore.

Things tried:

- created a new simple console application. -> Intellisense still not working.
- resetting VS-Settings by means of Tools/Import & Export Settings/Reset.  -> Intellisense still not working
- Changes to option settings in Text-Editor/C++/Advanced inclusive logging did not help.
  -> Intellisense still not working

There was actually an interesting observation:

Intellisense normally creates a directory 'ipch' in the solution directory to store intermediate files. In my solution folders it disappeared as soon as the solution was opened. When I created a folder 'ipch' and opened the solution Intellisense removed the folder again - strange.

The final fix:

During the last week some new Windows updates were installed. I noticed some other unusual behaviour of my PC as well. After having created an image of my PC, I decided to 
uninstall Windows updates from 2013-09-11 (4 packages) and one update from 2013-08-28. 
(unfortunately I did not note down the KB-numbers)

AND: out of a sudden Intellisense is working again !

Maybe this report could be helpful for some other persons. 
Automatic Updates are now disabled on my PCs.

Comment: You disabled automatic updates because it interfered with intellisense! I don't think that's advice I would recommend for everyone. There's also no proof here that uninstalling the update was the cause of intellisense working again (as you say some days it works, some days it doesn't). Unusual activity on your PC after an update is common, usually it's .NET optimizing itself. Personally I just disable intellisense, for me its a resource hog and of questionable utility.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed 100%

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel
Microsoft NET framework 4.0.30319 RTMRel

Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3

Intellisense stops working after installing KB2876217.

Intellisense is back after removing update.

Comment: This is the right method for my case. It fixed my VS 2010 C++ Intellisense issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and also had the idea that one of the Windows Updates is buggy, so I can confirm your report.

I tried to uninstall them one-b<-one and found the "bad guy":

KB2876217 destroys intellisense for VS2010 under XP SP3.

A supported hotfix is available from Microsoft to fix this issue. Check at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2526044/en-us

Comment: The hotfix is not available anymore through the links given in the article. I simply removed KB2876217 because I had no option.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it may not be such a good idea to uninstall update KB2876217. Instead, install Visual Studio SP1 update (if not already installed) and then install update KB2526044. I have tried it before and it does work...