# Visual Studio 2010 intellisense stopped working completely

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I've had this problem for a long time. At some point IntelliSense just stopped working on my laptop, completely. Whenever I type in a `.`, `->` or `(`, it says

> IntelliSense: 'No additional information available' (See 'Troubleshooting IntelliSense in C++ Projects' for further help.)

It doesn't work in any projects, even if I make a new blank one. Hovering over identifiers doesn't show any information either. Furthermore, some actions such as go to definition used to completely freeze the studio, until I did a full settings reset and that problem was resolved. But intellisense is still not working. Is there anything I can do, short of full reinstall? (If that would even help.. besides I doubt I can find the CD now.)

**Update:** this question describes the exact issue I was having: [VS2010 Intellisense problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798270/vs2010-intellisense-problems)

Since I already tried installing service packs and something didn't go right, I went with a rather hacky solution - I replaced my ole32.dll with an older version, which seems to have fixed the issue. This is obviously not recommended if you care about your system's stability, but if you're still running WinXP, chances are that you don't ;)

Comment: Forgot to mention that I did try installing every SP I could find, to no avail. But if I remember correctly it could indeed have been caused by some winxp update. It is possible that my installation is completely messed up now due to installing and re-installing SP's. Its a very old issue that I've been coping with and trust me, I've probably read every existing question/topic/article on this problem :) Also, the accepted answer in that question gives a broken link, so its of no use.